# Unable to pass intent parameters and start service when consuming an SDK

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sdk

I have an Android studio project comprised of two modules:
1. A library I'm developing which has a single class which will be exposed to client apps (MySDK)
2. A test app which will consume methodes within the library. (MyTestApp)

For some reason, when I call the (SomeService) class via an intent with parameters, the parameters are not passed and the 
class is never invoked. 
The message I receive in Android Monitor is:  "Not able to initialize class for SetValues: 
java.lang.Class

Also, the issue is not attributed to (SomeService) class. I've already proven this.
It may be attributed to how the context is passed since the SDK has no Activity associated with it.
But, I'm not sure.

I've tried numerous approaches with out much luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//1. MyTestApp (Main Activity)
public class MyTestApp extends AppCompatActivity {

String aUrl ="http://www.google.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_main);

    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);

    MySDK mySDK = new MySDK(this.getApplicationContext());
    mySDK.retrieveSomethingViaIntentService();
}
}

//2. MySDK
public class MySDK {

private static Context mCtx;

public MySDK(Context context) {
mCtx = context;
}

public void retrieveSomethingViaIntentService(){
               Intent i = new Intent(mCtx.getApplicationContext(), SomeService.class);
                i.putExtra("Label1", true);
                i.putExtra("Label2", false);
                mCtx.getApplicationContext().startService(i);
            }
}
```

Comment: how did you access the service class in main project from your library project?

Comment: I access it from my library project. (mCtx.getApplicationContext().startService(i);)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to include the [SomeService] class